# combine keys and values for given data

Tags: javascript

I have the following as the data set:

```js
var data = [{
  key: "A",
  value: "abc"
}, {
  key: "A",
  value: "def"
}, {
  key: "B",
  value: "abc"
}, {
  key: "B",
  value: "def"
}, {
  key: "B",
  value: "ghi"
}, {
  key: "A",
  value: "jkl"
}];
```

I want the combine the data set in the following way:

```js
var combinedData = [{
  key: ["A", "B"],
  value: ["abc", "def"]
}, {
  key: ["A"],
  value: ["ghi"]
}, {
  key: ["B"],
  value: ["jkl"]
}];
```

The code that I have tried so far has lead me to this:

```js
var myResult = [{
  key: "A",
  value: ["abc", "def", "ghi"]
}, {
  key: "B",
  value: ["abc", "def", "jkl"]
}];
```

Code used to get to the above scenario:

```js
var group_to_values = data.reduce(function (obj, item) {
    obj[item.key] = obj[item.key] || [];
    obj[item.key].push(item.value);
    return obj;
}, {});

var myResult = Object.keys(group_to_values).map(function (key) {
    return {key: key, value: group_to_values[key]};
});
```

I am stuck as to how should I proceed.. One of the thoughts is to check whether one is the subset of other in case of values and combine those.. Performance won't be an issue

Comment: It might be useful if you post the code that yields your current result.

Comment: The following is the code that I used to get myResult:

Comment: var group_to_values = data.reduce(function (obj, item) {
    obj[item.tag] = obj[item.tag] || [];
    obj[item.tag].push(item.dashboard);
    return obj;
}, {});

var myResult = Object.keys(group_to_values).map(function (key) {
    return {tag: key, dashboards: group_to_values[key]};
});

Comment: The expected pattern looks like the keys and values are swapped?

Comment: I need to combine keys and values together (which can be combined) basically doing a groupBy kind of thing

Comment: Start by making groupings of key to value arrays. Then create your final array by first finding and adding intersections among all the separate arrays, and then adding the remaining values as individual entries. If there can be multiple keys, I assume you'll want the narrowest intersection, followed by intersections in the remaining values until there are no more.

Comment: @HarshSapra on basis of what you want to combine data?(what is pattern for 'combinedData')

Comment: This is not a jquery question.  This is a logic question, which has nothing to do with dom manipulation.

Comment: @yajiv if the keys have same set/subset of values combine them

Comment: @Taplar I used jQuery tag as it contains some builtin functions to iterate over arrays and objects.. that was the intention

Comment: @doodlemeister is there any js library out there that can help me do this in a cleaner way?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach is an ES5 method which is pretty much universally implemented these days.  Much like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map .  Forcing the use of jQuery for things that can be done natively is not the best method, especially when they are not DOM elements.

Comment: @Taplar thanks for the useful js methods.. I will try to implement on my own

Comment: Yes, lodash has useful methods for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `reduce` to build the desired output.

And the helper functions like `includes` and `every` to find objects and make the necessary comparisons.

```js
var data = [{  key: "B",  value: "ghi"}, { key: "A",  value: "abc"}, {  key: "A",  value: "def"}, {  key: "B",  value: "abc"}, {  key: "B",  value: "def"}, {  key: "A",  value: "jkl"}, { key: "A",  value: "ele"}, { key: "B",  value: "ele"}];

var combinedData = Object.entries(data.reduce((a, c) => {
  if (a[c.value]) a[c.value].key.push(c.key);
  else a[c.value] = { key: [c.key]};
  return a;
}, {})).reduce((a, [value, keyObj]) => {
  var found = a.find((o) => o.key.length === keyObj.key.length && o.key.every((k) => keyObj.key.includes(k)));
  if (found) {
    found.value.push(value);
  } else {
    a.push({
      key: keyObj.key,
      value: [value]
    });
  }
  
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(combinedData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help.. I am debugging the code step by step to understand it fully before implementing it in my code

Comment: @HarshSapra great, if you have any question don't hesitate to ask me. `:)`

Comment: You can simplify a little by turning `a[c.value] = { key: [c.key]};` into `a[c.value] = [c.key];` since that object always has only one `key` property. However, I'm not understanding something. How can `a` be useful as a collection to search for keys when it's an incomplete set of data? Maybe I'm wrong, but it seems like you're trying to use your result as a point of reference before you actually have the full result. Does that really work?

Comment: Yeah, I think it doesn't quite work reliably. If you move the `{  key: "B",  value: "ghi"}` object to the first position in the `data` array, the result ends up being incorrect.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense now. You're gathering a collection of matching key sets, so you can search the existing collection to add a new corresponding value. Very nice.

Comment: @doodlemeister yes, `:)`